# Enumeration is found but not the values of it

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an enumeration that is defined in a class in the same namespace as my view models, and I want to use this enumeration in a data trigger in my view. The problem is that the enumeration is accessible, but not the values.

The code is this:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
    public enum MyEnumeration { Value1, Value2 }
}
```

My view:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"  

..........


<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyDependencyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:MyView}}}" Value="{x:Type vm:MyEnumeration.Value1}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

I get the error that nested properties are not supported.

How can I get the value of the enumeration that I want to use in the data trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `x:Static` instead of `x:Type` in your code.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyDependencyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:MyView}}}" Value="{x:Static local:MyEnumeration.Value1}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

From the documentation of the [`x:Static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xstatic-markup-extension) markup extension:

> References any static by-value code entity that is defined in a Common Language Specification (CLS)–compliant way. The static property that is referenced can be used to provide the value of a property in XAML.
>
> The code entity that is referenced must be one of the following:
>
> - A constant
> - A static property
> - A field
> - **An enumeration value**